# Can I have Google Calendar auto-write to my calendar, but not subscribe?

Tags: google-calendar

I've got a problem that's annoying me. I recently enrolled at a university course (for fun, after hours) and they naturally provided me with a my@school.com email and calendar. My "my@school.com" email subscribes to the "course@school.com" calendar through Google Calendar, but I want it in my@work calendar as well. (please see my crude flow chart below).

I don't have permissions to subscribe to course@school.com calendar from my@work email (naturally), but I can subscribe to my@school calendar from my@work calendar. So my question is, is there any way to have the course@school.com calendar auto-write events to my@school calendar? That way, since subscribing to the my@school calendar for my@work calendar, it would populate in my@work calendar.

This is not a major problem so I'm not planning on coding up any solution for it. I'm just asking for existing solutions, and if there's nothing out there I'm just gonna have to do it manually. I'm looking for quick fixes here ;)

[image]